# getting error "error: unknown option `--nonPersistent" when using expo publish

Tags: react-native, expo

I have build an app using expo init and it is working perfectly fine with "expo start". But when I wanted to publish it using "expo publish", i get the error.

```
(base) hemant@hemant-hp:~/Desktop/Chatter-Native$ expo publish
┌──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┐
│                                                                                                                                          │
│   There is a new version of expo-cli available (3.11.2).                                                                                 │
│   You are currently using expo-cli 3.2.3                                                                                                 │
│   Install expo-cli globally using the package manager of your choice; for example: `npm install -g expo-cli` to get the latest version   │
│                                                                                                                                          │
└──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘
Unable to find an existing Expo CLI instance for this directory, starting a new one...
error: unknown option `--nonPersistent'

Metro Bundler process exited with code 1
Set EXPO_DEBUG=true in your env to view the stack trace.
(base) hemant@hemant-hp:~/Desktop/Chatter-Native$
```

Answer (score 1):

maybe it's because you are using a old version of expo-cli, upgrade your expo-cli and try again. you can get a more detailed log of your error runing $export EXPO_DEBUG=true and runing again expo publish